# Usage of 'is' and 'are'

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I've just finished watching an episode of an american tv series. At the end of the episode, the narrator said, 'there **is** only two episodes left'. My question is: because *two episodes* is plural and countable, oughtn't it be 'there **are** only two episodes left'? I find this a bit of confusing, maybe because english isn't my first language, but until now, I thought that the language rules regarding this case aren't that complicated... Thanks!

Comment: Oh thanks, I've searched for existing questions but I didn't find anything with the search terms 'is' and 'are'.

Comment: After reading the thread I was pointed to, I didn't find it that enlightening. Then, after googling for some time, I found this link to be very clear: http://www.redlinels.com/2012/07/13/theres-with-plural-nouns/ I hope this helps someone else, too!

Comment: Perhaps you're in a position to give a better answer to the other question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did they say "there is" or "there's"?

The correct language would be "there are only two...". However, when this is said with a contraction, many speakers feel that "there're" (for "there are") sounds awkward, and instead say "there's" which is improper but sounds right.

You can almost think of "there's" being a contraction for "there are".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clarified everything. I watched the ending again and again, but for me, as a non native speaker, it's hard to hear / not absolutely clear. I believe that I can hear the "i" from "there is" but im not absolutely sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what *The Cambridge Grammar of English* (p242) has to say on this issue:

> When the copula is cliticised to the subject in informal style, many
>   speakers use the third-person singular form irrespective of the number
>   of the post-verbal NP. *There's only two problems remaining.* This
>   pattern suggests the verb agreement is simply with *there*, treated as a
>   3rd person singular pronoun like *it*.
>
> When the copula is pronounced as a full independent word, the
>   person-number properties of the verb match those of the post-verbal NP
>   ... .

So it appears that following the cliticised *is* in *there's* with a plural noun is not uncommon in informal language. It suggests that the TV presenter said: *There's only two episodes left*, not *There is only two episodes left*.

Answer (score 0):

[redlinels.com/2012/07/13/theres-with-plural-nouns](http://redlinels.com/2012/07/13/theres-with-plural-nouns)

I add this as an answer because it answered my question. After reading the thread I was pointed to, I didn't find it that enlightening. Then, after googling for some time, I found this link to be very clear. I hope this helps someone else, too!

Comment: It's a good idea to summarize what you link to (and to properly format them as hyperlinks so that people can click through).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought the link were klickable but it obviously wasn't. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement, but you should still summarize what you're linking to. “Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.” ([answer])